# AWS EC2 server- http traffic not reaching server

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, http

I am new to AWS and I have a t2 micro instance. I am only using it to host a static website with nginx.

What is really strange is the public ipaddress(which I use for SSH) is not the same as the eth0 ip address. Because of this, http traffic is not reaching the server when I use my ssh public ipaddress in the URL.

I am not using any customary security groups. Everything is default right now.

How do I get http traffic to the server when the public ip address is different than the eth0 address? Or how do I get the http traffic to reach my server? The nginx logs show not access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS public IPs are NATted to the instances. Hence you only see the private IP for eth0. You need to configure a security group to allow TCP traffic to port 80.